# mysql - insert into one table from another with conditions from a third table

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-tables

How do you insert into table A all the rows from table B that match a condition from table C?

For instance,

```
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE tableB.id=tableC.id;
```

This does not work, because mysql does not recognize tableC.

Comment: Try adding 'TableC' into your subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then add **tableC** after **From** keyword and use **tableB.*** instead of *

```
 INSERT INTO tableA SELECT tableB.* FROM tableB,tableC WHERE tableB.id=tableC.id;
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I missed that. I'll accept in 9 minutes :)